# Read only the first item of a feed

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Is there a way to simply read the first item of an rss feed instead to read all?
 I  use actualy `WebClient` with `DownloadStringAsync` method but that read all.

Comment: Create a feed reader and then create objects from the xml. Put them in a list and that's it. And where's your code.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using `HttpWebRequest` and add a Range header.
 But I don't know if is possible with Windows Phone